# new operator help, type-specifier and other errors

Tags: c++, syntax-error, new-operator

```
class Student
{
    Book* m_book[8];

public:
    Student()
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            m_book[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    ~Student()
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            delete m_book[j];
        }
    }

    void addBook(Book& book)
    {
        int k = 0;
        while(m_book[k] != NULL){
            k++;
        }
            Book book = new m_book[k];

    }
};
```

Why is the `addBook` member function not working?

Comment: It's "working" (kind of), but seemingly not as you expect. What are you actually expecting? Please add this to the question, and also what you are observing! Thanks :)

Comment: it should be m_book[k] = new Book. btw you should conaider using std::vector instead of that array. voting to close

Comment: @DanielKovachev with the change you suggest it's working exactly 8 times. `std::vector` seems indeed the best solution here.

Comment: @Wolf well the function add book sounds like he is trying to add a book to his array. if he wants more than 8 he should conaider using vector or other stl continer

Comment: Side note : Don't use `new` but rather `std::array<std::unique_ptr<Book>, 8>`.

Comment: Is there some reason why you are using an array and not std::vector? I realize that sometimes students need to use arrays by requirement, but if this is not the case, there is no reason to use an array. Constructor would become {m_book.clear()}, Destructor won't be necessary, addBook would become {m_book.push_back(book);} (last one assuming that Book has everything which is necessary for a copy, that is either being a simple class or having everything that the Rule of Three requires).

Comment: Another thing, every answer to your problem needs the semantics - I see that m_book stores pointers, is that for a reason? (since usually one wants to avoid pointers whenever possible) Especially since it seems like you copy the object in add_book anyway. Only thing that I can think of that would make it reasonable to be a pointer would be that books can't be actually copied, which would require unique pointers. Also, has the restriction on only 8 books any reason we need to know about or is the 8 an arbitrary number to make it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Book book = new m_book[k];
```

should be

```
   m_book[k]=new Book(book);
```

Comment: you forget to add the book he recieve in his function. Book *newbook = new Book(book);

Comment: I think the first line of the answer should not repeat this horrible NonC++ line. Better make explicit that its wrong by some introductory words.

Comment: i dont think its a good idie since book can be deleted in any point of time. and i am pretty sure you will not be able to compile it beacuse he hold array of pointers. people use cpp like its c,  its really sad

Comment: @DanielKovachev Thanks.

Comment: Simply to few text to be a good answer. Those do-this answers don't help much learning *why* something is wrong and something right.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with the line `Book book = new m_book[k];`

- You are trying to assign a `pointer to type` to a Book, which is invalid
- You are using `operator new` on the value m_book[k], not a type

You also have an array of book pointers, with ownership semantics. You don't need the pointers, you could just have an array of Books directly.

A much simplified Student:

```
class Student 
{
    std::array<Book, 8> m_books;
    size_t count = 0;
public:
    void addBook(const Book & book)
    {
        m_book[count] = book;
        ++count;
    }
}
```

No pointers, default constructor, default destructor

Comment: *`No pointers`* can also be a bad idea, if the student only uses the book and doesn't a deep copy ... I'm not sure what students prefer these days ;) either way good to say that `Book book = new m_book[k];` is wrong (whereas maybe good for Spreedshirt)